# Does git provide a URL scheme for directly referencing a version of a file?

Tags: git

Is there some sort of URL scheme for git that allows you to directly reference a particular file in a version? Example:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/5aee96329ab7869cbe90cf80fd2a3f8f4dc5dccf/include/git2/branch.h

In this URL we have basically [protocol]://[repo location]/blob/[version hash]/[file path]

I'm assuming this link scheme is something GitHub made up, and not something that could be used anywhere else. Given that, is there anything similar I could use on non-GitHub implementations of git? something like:

git://[repo location]/[version hash]/[file path] ?

I know I could programmatically look it up given the version hash and file path, but I'm more interested in the easy referential abilities a URL provides.

Comment: Are you looking for a schema to use in your own manual process or one that git natively supports?

Comment: Preferably natively supported by git. If there's something that isn't native, but has broad acceptance, I'll look into that.

Comment: This is a github thing.

I have seen several arguments on line to why this is not needed, due to the distributed nature of git, but I would like for git to have a way to get a particular version of a file from a central server.  The fact that git supports centralized servers, makes this desirable.

The command `git show [version label]:[file path]` only works if you already have the repository locally.  Some repositories are large enough where getting the whole source is not desirable.

Comment: Somebody needs to invent something like it. I would like it for an intranet-type situation to reference specific versions. If I can do something like file://servername/directory/file, I should be able to do something like git://servername/repo/path/file. Using `git show` or other command isn't 'clickable', especially when your users aren't terminal-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitweb` supports the following scheme, per the man page: `.../gitweb.cgi/<repo>/<action>/<revision>:/<path>?<arguments>`

Here `<revision>` may be symbolic, e.g. `HEAD`; I suppose you can use commit hashes and tags, too.

Obviously GitHub uses a different URL mapping.

Note that `git-daemon` speaks its own protocol, and `git-http-backend` does not seem to serve individual files; there's no 'native' URL scheme.

Comment: Bummer. It could really use one.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a local repo:

```
git show [version hash]:[file path]
```

Note the colon.